# Usage of signal.welch

Tags: python, signal-processing

I want to use python signal.welch. The usage of signal.welch is as follows,

f, Pxx_den = signal.welch(x, fs, nperseg=1024)

In my case, x is for example gyroscopy signal ( 1 x 1024 samples (for about 10 sec data)), fs = 100 Hz. In my case, how can I decide nperseg? I want to know how I can select nperseg when the number of samples of the input is 1024 (about 10 sec).

Answer (score 4):

[scipy.signal.welch](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) estimates the power spectral density by dividing the data into segments and averaging periodograms computed on each segment. The `nperseg` arg is the segment length and (by default) also determines the FFT size.

On the one hand, making `nperseg` smaller allows the input to divide into more segments, good for more averaging to get a more reliable estimate. On the other hand, making `nperseg` larger improves the frequency resolution of the result. In any case, `nperseg` should be smaller than the input size in order to get multiple segments.

The default segment length is 256 samples, which seems like a reasonable starting point for a 1024-sample input.